# Post-hoc test in two-way ANOVA

Tags: anova, spss, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc

I am doing a two-way independent ANOVA using type of organisational change (5 levels) and job level (7 levels) within the organisation as the factors (in SPSS). I followed Andy Field's procedure (*Discovering Statistics Using SPSS*, third edition) and I cannot manage to get the option of Post-Hoc tests for cases where equal variance is not assumed, i.e. Games-Howell.

I searched the syntax help files and somewhere there's a note saying that when using more than one factor Games-Howell cannot be performed. However, Andy Field did it! (please see page 434 of his book). Any ideas how can I do the same?

Comment: In the options of Post-Hoc, down there are some options that you can selected as Games-Howell.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether there's a better way but perhaps you can run one-way anovas on factor 1 for each category group of factor 2 separately?

You would use `split files ...` for this.

Try it and see whether that duplicates Andy's results.

Comment: I see what you mean, the only thing I can think of is that Andy had one factor (gender) with only two categories.